# Basic: How to get a photo's PID?

Tags: fbml, photo

Newbie question:

On this page:
http://www.facebook.com/KCCFullThrottle?sk=app_139518349451248

I would like to post this photo:
http://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.163774783731433.32229.162385797203665&type=3

According to the Facebook page for fb:photo

All I need to do is add this FBML:
`<fb:photo pid="12345" />`

But, can I / where do I find the PID for a photo without writing API calls? (Multiple searches, no luck.)

`<b>`

Answer (score 0):

The photo pid is only available in the graph API, whether you use the graph objects or query the FQL objects.  FBML is being deprecated, so please don't use that.